# Sublime text 2 forces uppercase Ll' in comments

Tags: sublimetext2

This is really strange. In my EmberJS code, I have comments for the properties. For whatever reason all the l's in all my comments in every *.js files are uppercase. If I try to change them to lowercase, I get upper case. If I remove the comment wrapper, the 'l' becomes lower case. If I restore the comment wrapper, it automagically becomes upper case again. This does not happen on my colleagues installation of Sublime. I have version 2.0.2 build 2221. If I copy the text into Notepad, the l's are lower case. Here's an example:

```
   This is the property that determines if the textarea is disabLed

   @property disabLed

   @type booLean

   @default false



disabled: false,
```

Remove the comment wrapper:

```
   This is the property that determines if the textarea is disabled

   @property disabled

   @type boolean

   @default false

disabled: false
```

Its not a camelcase issue from what I can see, as I have some comments where there are multiple l's and they're all uppercase, for example ceLL. It only happens with the l's.

Does anyone know what's going on? Where is the setting that says, Don't change the case of my l's?

Answer (score 0):

I met strange Sublime's behaviours as well. It might be really tricky to define the causes.

I think it would be better not to spend too much time on it and just reset ST to default settings:
https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/revert.html

GL!